# How to properly refresh scope when changing state in ui.router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am using ui.router to manage the state of some pages on my app.   When I change state I would like the controller to reload the objects in scope.  However I am not finding a way to tie into state change to do this.

Is there a way I can hook into the state transition and fire a request for my angular resource?

Here are my two state transitions, which are in separate functions.

```
$state.transitionTo('myObj.current', {myObjId: $scope.myObj.myObjId});

$state.transitionTo('myObj.current.edit', {myObjId: $scope.myObj.myObjId});
```

When the state changes I would like to call the _getMyObjDetails function.

```
var   _getMyObjDetails = function (myObjId) {
      var _myObj = MyObjService.get({myObjId: myObjId});
      _myObj.$promise.then(function (data) {
        $scope.myObj = data;
        ngProgress.complete();
      });
      return _myObj;
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you properly, I think the only thing you need to do is listen the $stateChangeStart event. You can inject the $rootScope into your controller and make it like so:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) { /* Your code... */ });
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I ended up using $stateChangeSuccess, but this got me close enough :).  Thanks!